# Python: Use polyval to predict X passing Y

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting

I have 2 sets of points (X, Y). I want to:

- Use polifit to fit the line
- Given a Y predict an X

This is the dataset:

```py
            X     Y
      -0.00001  5.400000e-08
      -0.00001  5.700000e-08
       0.67187  1.730000e-07
       1.99997  9.150000e-07
       2.67242  1.582000e-06
       4.00001  3.734000e-06
       4.67193  5.414000e-06
       5.99998  9.935000e-06
       6.67223  1.311300e-05
       8.00000  2.102900e-05
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Data to be fitted]

I have seen numpy has the function [polyval](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval). But here you pass an X and get a y. How do i reverse it.

Comment: Reserve the whole `x` and `y`? I think that should work.

Comment: This could work, howver as you see from the dataset the first 2 x points are the same. Can you use polifit by having 2 X values (since it is reversed it would be the y) that have 1 single Y value (the X) ?

Comment: It's not clear to me at all: how can you have two x points that are the same? That makes the whole polynomial fitting ambiguous, since it's not a function (from a mathematical point of view). Having the same Y value multiple times is fine, it just means the function is non-injective.

Comment: It's real data from an electrical measurment.  I could remove every repeating X value. Would still have reapeating Y values though (Since the Y is the change of current, whilst the X voltage i am changing). 

But then if i reverse it (make the change in current the X, and the Voltage the Y), now i would have the same X(current) associated with 2 Y (voltage values)

Comment: Well, that's a more interesting question, since this function doesn't have an inverse. In that case, I'd subtract the certain y value from the dataset, fit a polynomial and find its roots.

Comment: is there a python library suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can subtract the `y` value, fit an appropriate degree polynomial, then find it's roots. `numpy` is easily good enough for that task.
Here is a simple example:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10.1, 0.3)
y = x ** 2

def find_x_from_y(x, y, deg, value, threshold=1E-6):

    # subtract the y value, fit a polynomial, then find the roots of it
    r = np.roots(np.polyfit(x, y - value, deg))

    # return only the real roots.. due to numerical errors, you
    # must introduce a threshold value to its complex part.
    return r.real[abs(r.imag) < threshold]
```

```py
>>> find_x_from_y(x, y, 2, 0.5)
array([ 0.70710678, -0.70710678])
```

Finding roots is a numerical algorithm, it produces the numerical approximation of the actual roots. This might result in really small, but nonzero imaginary parts. To avoid this, you need a small threshold to distingush real and imaginary roots. This is why you can't really use `np.isreal`:

```py
>>> np.isreal(3.2+1E-7j)
False
```

A visual example with a 3 degree polynomial:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 10.1, 0.3)
y = x ** 3 - 3 * x ** 2 - 9 * x

def find_x_from_y(x, y, deg, value, threshold=1E-6):
    r = np.roots(np.polyfit(x, y - value, deg))
    return r.real[abs(r.imag) < threshold]

value = -10
rts = find_x_from_y(x, y, 3, value)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axhline(value, color="r")
for r in rts:
    plt.axvline(r, color="k")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: thanks! could you just expand on (or link an explanation)  "due to numerical errors, you
    # must introduce a threshold value to its complex part". Is polyfit introducing errors or?