# Python polyfit: evaluate error of predicting X from a given Y

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

Following on from "[Python: Use polyval to predict X passing Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668483/python-use-polyval-to-predict-x-passing-y)".

Given x,y arrays, i have:

- fitted a polynomial
- predicted x from y

Now i want to evaluate the error in predicted x, i want to:

- find error of predicted x for each y
- plot predicted X_error vs x
- evaluate a total error for the fitted x

I only want 1 predicted x from each y.

When i do it wtih example data, it works, but when i use my real data i get an error.

Here is the example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(0, 10.1, 0.3)
y = x ** 2

def find_x_from_y(x, y, deg, value, threshold=1E-6):

    # subtract the y value, fit a polynomial, then find the roots of it
    r = np.roots(np.polyfit(x, y - value, deg))

    # return only the real roots.. due to numerical errors, you
    # must introduce a threshold value to its complex part.
    return r.real[abs(r.imag) < threshold]

error=[] #stores the error prediciton
 #for each pair x_, y_ predict an X_predict from y_, find error between X_predict and x_
for x_, y_ in zip(x,y): 
  X_predict=find_x_from_y(x, y, deg=2, value=y_, threshold=1e-6)
  er=[] #store the error for each pair
  for x_value in X_predict: 
    er.append(abs(x_value-x_)/x_) #store the error values for each Xpredict
  error.append(min(er)) #get the min error for the pair (one closest to the line.)


plt.plot(x, error)
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image: Error for example]

However when i run it with my real x,y i get an error:

```py
x=  np. array([0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 2e-05,
 0.0,
 0.37924,
 0.8953899999999999,
 1.4268100000000001,
 1.91924,
 2.00252,
 2.38083,
 2.89537,
 3.42677,
 3.91914,
 4.00256,
 4.3807,
 4.89479,
 5.42592,
 5.91835,
 6.00251,
 6.38115,
 6.89497,
 7.42612,
 7.91851,
 8.00257,
 8.381039999999999,
 8.894919999999999,
 9.42628,
 9.91816,
 10.0026,
 10.380989999999999,
 10.89439,
 11.42538,
 11.91785,
 12.00268])

y= np. array([6.54e-07,
 6.529999999999999e-07,
 6.54e-07,
 6.559999999999999e-07,
 6.5e-07,
 1.183e-06,
 3.1e-06,
 6.71e-06,
 1.1588e-05,
 1.248e-05,
 1.7492e-05,
 2.5866e-05,
 3.6342e-05,
 4.7776000000000005e-05,
 4.9837e-05,
 5.9881000000000005e-05,
 7.5359e-05,
 9.3328e-05,
 0.000111899,
 0.000115321,
 0.00013085200000000001,
 0.000153994,
 0.000180015,
 0.000206199,
 0.00021114400000000002,
 0.00023249400000000003,
 0.000263802,
 0.00029832,
 0.00033244800000000005,
 0.000339169,
 0.00036652,
 0.000405955,
 0.000448722,
 0.000490421,
 0.0004989430000000001])

error=[] #stores the error prediciton
 #for each pair x_, y_ predict an X_predict from y_, find error between X_predict and x_
for x_, y_ in zip(x,y): 
  X_predict=find_x_from_y(x, y, deg=2, value=y_, threshold=1e-6)
  er=[] #store the error for each pair
  for x_value in X_predict: 
    er.append(abs(x_value-x_)/x_) #store the error values for each Xpredict
  error.append(min(er)) #get the min error for the pair (one closest to the line.)


plt.plot(x, error)
plt.show()
```

OUT:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7a5a113882dd> in <module>()
    108   for x_value in X_predict:
    109     er.append(abs(x_value-x_)/x_) #store the error values for each Xpredict
--> 110   error.append(min(er)) #get the min error for the pair (one closest to the line.)
    111 
    112 

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

- What is the best way of evaluating my predicted X values?

Comment: Have you checked that `X_predict` is not empty before the `for x_value in X_predict:` loop? The error you get clearly states that the `er` you give to `min()` is empty...

Comment: @Energya, I have checked and that is the issue. I had solved it using an if statement and a continue when X_predict was empty. However then i had the issue of a shorter error array than the x array. I would like to have a prediction for every value. I didn't add this to the code on stack because it would make it less clear.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand why your function `find_x_from_y` returns the roots of your polynomial, but you use them as `X_predict`

Comment: X_predict=find_x_from_y(x, y, deg=2, value=y_, threshold=1e-6) : predics the x values for a given y (value=y_). X_predicts however returns an array of predictions, and i just want 1, the one that is closest to my actual x value (i these cases eliminate teh negative x prediction). error.append(min(er)) keeps only the error with the minimum value (therefore the x_value of X_predict that is closest to the real x)